# SCNAction callback called only once on device and properly on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

## Edit

I compared the outcome between runs on an iPhone (6+, 9.3 (13E5200d)), which is my default and the iOS simulator (6+ 9.3 (13E5200d)). The simulator works as expected. Why the discrepancy between the two?

I have a seemingly simple setup where on touch I want to execute series of animations. To do that I employ `SCNAction`. After each animation I want to reevaluate certain things, so instead of a long `SCNAction.sequence()`, I have a `step` function that I call in the completion handler. The problem is that the completion handler is not called after an arbitrary number of steps.

In this instance it's one step.

```
let path = [
  SCNAction.sequence([
    SCNAction.moveBy(SCNVector3(2.7, 0, 0), duration: 0.25),
    SCNAction.waitForDuration(1)
  ]),
  SCNAction.sequence([
    SCNAction.moveBy(SCNVector3(2.7, 0, 0), duration: 0.25),
    SCNAction.waitForDuration(1)
  ]),
  SCNAction.sequence([
    SCNAction.moveBy(SCNVector3(2.7, 0, 0), duration: 0.25),
    SCNAction.waitForDuration(1)
  ]),
]

let nodeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 2.7, height: 2.7, length: 2.7, chamferRadius: 0)
nodeGeometry.firstMaterial = SCNMaterial()
nodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
let node = SCNNode(geometry: nodeGeometry)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

func step (index: Int) {
  print(index, "enter")
  node.runAction(path[index]) {
    print(index, "callback")
    if ((index + 1) < path.count) {
      step(index + 1)
    }
  }
}

step(0)
```

This code produces the following sequence

```
0 enter
0 callback
1 enter
```

I'm not getting the second callback. Why? How do I know when an `SCNAction` has finished executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code in an OS X playground and it worked perfectly. The red block moves to the right and disappears offscreen.

```
0 enter
0 callback
1 enter
1 callback
2 enter
2 callback
```

Your use of `runAction(_:completionHandler:)`, defined on the `SCNActionable` protocol, looks right.

EDIT: I tried with iPad and iPhone hardware running 9.2, under Xcode 7.2.x and 7.3.beta3. The code below, slightly modified to appease the Clang gods, works just as you described what you're looking for. To run, start with an Xcode SceneKit game template, replace the GameViewController definition with the code below, and leave the rest of the project alone.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

let path = [
    SCNAction.sequence([
        SCNAction.moveBy(SCNVector3(2.7, 0, 0), duration: 0.25),
        SCNAction.waitForDuration(1)
        ]),
    SCNAction.sequence([
        SCNAction.moveBy(SCNVector3(2.7, 0, 0), duration: 0.25),
        SCNAction.waitForDuration(1)
        ]),
    SCNAction.sequence([
        SCNAction.moveBy(SCNVector3(2.7, 0, 0), duration: 0.25),
        SCNAction.waitForDuration(1)
        ]),
]
var boxNode: SCNNode?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SCNScene()
    let sceneView = view as! SCNView
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    let nodeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 2.7, height: 2.7, length: 2.7, chamferRadius: 0)
    nodeGeometry.firstMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    nodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
    boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: nodeGeometry)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode!)

    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 1))
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3Make(7, 0, 4)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    step(0)
}

func step (index: Int) {
    print(index, "enter")
    boxNode!.runAction(path[index]) {
        print(index, "callback")
        if ((index + 1) < self.path.count) {
            self.step(index + 1)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this leaves the other parts of the scene that might be causing the problem...

Comment: The code in the question is already using `runAction(_:completionHandler:)` — it's just with trailing closure syntax, so the second parameter label is elided.

Comment: Oops, you're right! I copy/pasted into a playground, though, and it worked just fine. Puzzling that OP is seeing only one call.

Comment: I was testing this on an iPhone, after running the same code on the simulator I saw the expected behaviour. Could this be related to the 9.3 beta? @HalMueller @rickster?

Comment: @HalMueller thanks for the update. Given that this works for you, I'm certain now that it's my hardware running 9.3 that's to blame. Took some time to get there :)